# GCC bug in range-based for statement

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, for-loop, g++

I seem to have encountered a strange bug in GCC. Consider

```
for (int i = 5 : {1, 2, 3})
     std::cout << i << ", ";
```

While this nonsensical code is [correctly rejected by Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/260b834a9c2f9d64), [it compiles and executes fine on all recent GCC versions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08f4f774efd71285). The strange thing is that no output at all, neither `1, 2, 3` nor `5, 5, 5`, is produced.

If we now go further and consider this code

```
int arr[] {1, 2, 3};
for (int i = 5: arr)
    std::cout << i << ", ";
```

GCC warns us [that the **array is not used**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5265016250920e7d), which implies that the loop is ignored.

Does this code invoke undefined behavior? Or is it ill-formed, with no diagnostic required? Or is it simply a weird bug?
The standard specifies in [stmt.ranged]/1 that the declaration is substituted into the following line:

> *for-range-declaration* `= *__begin;`

... and such a declaration would clearly be ill-formed.

Edit: After [reporting the bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63985), Paolo Carlini has fixed it for version 5.0.

Comment: Nice find. Have you reported the bug?

Comment: @Aleksandar It might not be a bug but just the result of undefined behavior, see above.

Comment: It's not UB, that's just invalid syntax.  GCC should reject it unless it has an extension designed to handle it (which is extremely unlikely).

Comment: It's not accepted intentionally, so please report it. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ - thanks!

Comment: @Columbo as a side note, I get output 5 when compiling with g++4.9.2. It fails under clang++.

Comment: I compiled (both the 1st and 2nd code) with g++ 4.8.1, and there are no output at all.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I see that you've confirmed my report. Unfortunately one cannot edit the posts on bugzilla...

Comment: @vsoftco Interesting. Just one 5, or more?

Comment: @Columbo just one 5. I submitted before a bug report, you need to contact the admin directly and after couple of days will receive an email with the username/pass for posting on bugzilla.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both examples are invalid syntax, which requires a diagnostic.

The syntax for range-based for is in 6.5/1:

> *iteration-statement*:
>
> - ...
> - `for (` *for-range-declaration* `:` *for-range-initializer* `)` *statement*
>
> *for-range-declaration*:
>
> - *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *decl-specifier-seq* *declarator*

which does not allow for an initializer before the colon.

Comment: Doesn't a declarator consist of an initializer?

Comment: @remyabel No, it doesn't. An *init-declarator* can contain an initializer.